# Compile time check for consecutive functions call

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Suppose we have a class like this:

```
class OProcess {
  ...
  void Process1();
  void Process2(); // call only if Process1 wasn't called
  ...
}
```

such that function Process2() can be called *only* when function Process1() has NOT been called already.

**Is there a way to check that Process class is used correctly at compile-time?** I.e. compiler must give an error if Process1() CAN BE called before Process2() for some instance of OProcess object.

P.S. I understand that there can be code like this:

```
 if (variable == 1000)
   Process1();
 Process2();
```

and compiler can't be sure that Process1() will be called before Process2(). But here compiler can be sure that Process1() CAN be called before Process2() for some values of variable. And I need it to make an error or at least warning.

Comment: No, you can't make the compiler check runtime constraints.

Comment: I suppose your problem is undecidable in its general form, even if you had the liberty to fix your compiler so that it tries to (statically) check such (dynamic) behaviors.

Comment: If you could do this, then you would not need to run your program at all, because its output would be known in advance.

Comment: Why not bung the init stuff into the constructor. Then when the `run` comes around thre object has allk the bits and picese.

Comment: @Ed Heal, ok I have changed the functions names:)

Comment: You could have Process1 return an object of a type that exposes the Process2 function. But then how would you prevent someone calling Process1 or Process2 twice? In general it is not usually worth putting a lot of effort into stopping a class being used wrong; instead make it as easy as possible to use right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is **Somewhat**.

---

The long answer is: C++ does not implement [Linear Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_type_system#Linear_type_systems), thus uniqueness checks cannot be done at compile-time (fully). Still, reading this description gives us a trick: to implement this in the compiler, language designer forbid aliasing and enforce *consumption*.

So, if you agree that *some* runtime checks are allowed, then this can be done by having processes *consume* the object:

```
class OProcess {
public:
};

std::unique_ptr<OProcessed1> process1(std::unique_ptr<OProcess> op);
std::unique_ptr<OProcess>    process2(std::unique_ptr<OProcess> op);
```

Where `OProcessed1` is a proxy over `OProcess` presenting a *restricted interface* that exposes only those operations allowed on `OProcess` after that `Process1` was called.

The runtime part of the checks is that:

```
void func(std::unique_ptr<OProcess> op) {
    process1(std::move(op));
    process2(std::move(op));
}
```

will compile, even though it is undefined behavior to do anything other than destruction/assignment to `op` after moving from it.

Comment: Is there mistake? OProcessed1 should be OProcess?

Comment: @klm123: no, it's exactly as it should. Calling `process1` **consumes** the instance of `OProcess` so that no other function (and thus not `process2`) can be called on it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have problems with compiler on OS10.9 currently and can't use c++11(or std::move). Could you explain in more details what exactly will happen when I implement such a "fund" function?

Comment: @klm123: it this case, you can use `std::auto_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr` and you will not need `std::move` (it'll be less self-explanatory, though). The simple idea is that `process1` consumes the object, so only a null pointer remains of what was the argument, and then spits out an object *of another type* which can thus have different properties (such as not having a `process2` function available).

Comment: I understand that with auto_ptr process1 will simply take all op information and process2 will get a NULL. But this is basically same run-time check, which @Mukul Kumar proposes.

Comment: @klm123: It is subtly different. There is indeed a runtime check, however it is a generic check (whenever you are passed a pointer, you have to check whether it is null or not); furthermore, it is *clear* in the API that the function consumes its input; finally, once compilers/static analyzers get upgraded for C++11 they shall warn you if you ever write a function like `func` because though C++ does implement linear typing, such linear analysis is trivial (same difficulty as uninitialized variables).

Comment: Ok. I guess nobody will propose something better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is either make init private and reduce the risk you mention,
or use dependency injection, as 'init' methods, or any logic at all inside the constructor, are bad practice in terms of clean code

Another trick is to have `ProcessBase` that defines `init` and calls it in it's constructor. `ProcessBase`'s constructor is called before the derived constructor, thus making sure that `init` is called before any logic is made in the derived class.

Edit:

- You may want to change the logic to have both methods private and have one method called `process3()` that will call the other methods in the correct order.
- Another option is to use the `decorator` design pattern and wrap one method in a class and have your decorator call them by order.

Comment: Sorry, I had to correct the question to make everything vise versa. I think my question is better illustrated this way. Sorry, this is model of situation from complicated code, which I can't show here, and I made an mistake.

Comment: @klm123, what i wrote still applies.

Comment: May be I don't understand you... Can you give an example of such decorator objects? And you defenetly can't include Process1 in Process2 in last edit.